# Reading Data from UnauthorizedAccessException leads to UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: databricks-unity-catalog

I am Using Databricks with Unity Catalog enabled.

In my Databricks Notebook I have a read call such as

```
spark.read.format("delta").load("abfss://container@ddd.dfs.core.windows.net/yy/xx/")
```

But I always get the following error message:

> com.databricks.sql.managedcatalog.acl.UnauthorizedAccessException:
> PERMISSION_DENIED: User does not have USE CATALOG on Catalog
> 'dddd'.

The Service Prinicpal Executing the Notebook has `ALL_PERMISSIONS` on the External Location. For me it is unclear, why the catalog is accessed....

I simply want to access the data from the storage account.

According to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/connect/unity-catalog/), access should still be possible:

> While Unity Catalog supports path-based access to external tables and
> external volumes using cloud storage URIs, Databricks recommends that
> users read and write all Unity Catalog tables using table names and
> access data in volumes using /Volumes paths.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/connect/unity-catalog/